# Aggregation mongoose $sum where

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have query something like this:

```
{"$match": {$or: [{"to": system.mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)}, {"from": system.mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)}]}},
        {"$sort": {"createDate": -1}},
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$conversationId",
                "from": {"$first": "$from"},
                "to": {"$first": "$to"},
                "content": {"$first": "$content"},
                "createDate": {"$first": "$createDate"},
                "unreaded": {"$sum": 1}
            }

        },
```

I don't need to edit main `$match` I just need to get sum of `unreaded` messages,

I need something like this: `"unreaded": {"$sum": 1, {$match: {unreaded: true}}}`

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$cond`

```
"unreaded": {"$sum": {$cond: {if: "$unreaded", then: 1, else: 0} }}
```

Documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/

Comment: How can I also add another cond to it? I also need to `$to` be equal to `system.mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)` Need somethig like this: `"unreaded": {"$sum": {$cond: {if: "$unreaded" && ("$to" == system.mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)), then: 1, else: 0} }}`  ?